# JPA/Hibernate Parent/Child relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I am quite new to JPA/Hibernate (Java in general) so my question is as follows (note, I have searched far and wide and have not come across an answer to this):

I have two entities:

Parent and Child (naming changed).

Parent contains a list of Children and Children refers back to parent.

e.g.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

@Id
@Basic
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "PARENT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private int id;        

    /* ..... */

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID", nullable = true)
    private Set<child> children;

    /* ..... */

}

@Entity
public class Child {

@Id
@Basic
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "CHILD_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private int id; 

    /* ..... */

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID")
private Parent parent;

    /* ..... */

}
```

I want to be able to do the following:

1. Retrieve a Parent entity which would contain a list of all its children (List), however, when listing Parent (getting List, it of course should omit the children from the results, therefore setting FetchType.LAZY.
2. Retrieve a Child entity which would contain an instance of the Parent entity.

Using the code above (or similar) results in two exceptions:

1. Retrieving Parent:
   A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML...
2. Retrieving Child:
   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: xxxxxxxxxxx, no session or session was closed

When retrieving the Parent entity, I am using a named query (i.e. calling it specifically)
    @NamedQuery(name = "Parent.findByParentId", query = "SELECT p FROM Parent AS p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.children where p.id = :id")

Code to get Parent (i.e. service layer):

```
public Parent findByParentId(int parentId) {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Parent.findByParentId");
    query.setParameter("id", parentId);

    return (Parent) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Why am I getting a LazyInitializationException event though the List property on the Parent entity is set as Lazy (when retrieving the Child entity)?

Comment: I prefer not using query.getSingleResult(), rather returning a list and checking for zero or one members.

Comment: other theme: use return em.find(Parent.class, Integer.valueOf(parentId));  instead of using the query.

Comment: other theme: use nullable ids like Integer, instead of primitive int.

Comment: I hope it is a typo in the question, not in your code. But your parent child set refers to an other child than the entity class! -- The Entity is `Child` (upper case 'c') and the Set is of type `child` with lower case letter!

Comment: @Ralph That is a typo! Should be `private Set<Child> children`

Comment: @Ralph Re em.find()... reason I'm using the query is to fetch the LAZY children

Comment: @NubieJ: now it is getting interessting, please post the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception 1. Your XML serialization does not have anything with JPA/Hibernate, you will be able to serialize your two-way-setup successfully. If automatic serialization fails, preprocess your to-be serialized objects in such a way that you remove the link from child to parent - outside the transaction (assuming you have automatic merges in your container).

Exception 2. You should read up on Transactions. In short, there are rules to when traversal of objects requiring database interaction can be done and not. Logically this divide must exist. If you want lazy relationships to behave as 'normal' (read: fetched) outside the transaction session, you simple 'prefetch' the relationship by traversing or accessing it in such a way that the relationship is resolved. For example call .size, or iterating over the members, on a set or a list will do this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
Regarding your answer on Exception 2. - I want the fetchtype to ALWAYS be lazy, unless specified otherwise, e.g. only when calling the named query on Parent (findByParentId) should it fetch the children.

Comment: - not when getting the Parent (property) when getting a Client entity.

Comment: If you get a child which has a parent with lazy relationship to the children, the parent-to-child relationship should not be resolved (fetched). However the big issue here is avoiding 1) getting many children and 2) having two database requests by the container. If you are worried about performance, check out the 'mappedBy' parameter in addition; it lets you add children to parent without resolving the parent-to-child relationship.

Comment: Something that I left out and that would probably make a big difference, is that this is done via a web service (for my first issue - therefore the XML)

Answer (score 1):

**ADDED**

Your mapping is a bit strange. What your mapping describe are **two different one directional Releation ships**:

- Parent -- 1:n -> Child
- Child -- n:1 -> Parent

which both are independend, but are stored in the same Database column.

I guess that this is not want you want, I guess that you want to have **one bidirectional relation ship**. The easyest way is to change the Parent's child Set mapping, to use `mappedBy` instead of `@JoinColumn`:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    ...
    /* fetch = FetchType.LAZY is default in one:many */
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy="parent")
    private Set<child> children;    
    ...   
}
```

From what you described in the comments of my old answer, this should fix the problem. Because if you now naviagate Parant -> Child -> Parent, both parent will be the same, and the persistence provider know it.

*Beware of the fact, that the relationship now is only maintained on the child side.*

**OLD**

When you get a `LazyInitializationException` then the problem is that the not loaded entity is not longer attached to the EntityManager. In most cases the problem is that the transaction is closed, before the entity is loaded.

You can do fore things:

- keep the transaction open
- load the entity before you close the transaction
- switch from lazy to eager load
- fix your mapping (see: the added part of my answer)

Comment: Let me clarify the issue around the LazyInitializationException:
I am trying to understand why the exception is thrown - but not what is causing the exception.  What I am after is why the Child list is loaded (or attempted to be) if it is set to LAZY and not being referenced. 

A call is made to bring back the Child entity which includes a property for the Parent entity.  So (in theory), it should bring back the Child entity, instance of the Parent entity and nothing for the Parent's children (since this is set to LAZY).

Comment: There are no other calls to e.g. Parent.children, so why is it trying to load?

Comment: @NubieJ: I seams to be a problem with the mapping, see the 'Added' part on top of my answer

Comment: Let me give it a go... will feedback as soon as I have results!

Comment: Same issue... getting parent gives me cycle issue (infinitely deep XML) and getting the child gives the LazyInitializationException.

Table (DB) structure is as follows:

    `Parent
    ----------------
    Parent_Id (PK)
    Name

    Child
    ----------------
    Child_Id (PK)
    Name
    Parent_Id (FK)`

Idea is to be able to get a parent with all its children (single method call).  Then when I want to work with a Child entity (different scenario), I want to be able to get the Parent entity in order to have access to e.g. name property.

Comment: When doing this, the Parent and NONE of the LAZY set OneToMany properties should be part of the Child entity.

Comment: Please note my comment above:
_Something that I left out and that would probably make a big difference, is that this is done via a web service (for my first issue - therefore the XML)_

Comment: @NubieJ - After you transfer anything you by a web serive then the transfered object will not be attached to the Entity manager, and this can causes LazyInitialization exceptions, if the referenced object was not loaded before transfering it.

Comment: I understand that, but why is this happening even though the object is not being referenced?  There are no calls to e.g. child.Parent.children...

Comment: @NubieJ: what do you mean by: "even though the object is not being referenced"?

Comment: Looks like this (LazyInitializationException) is being caused when the object is being serialized - any ideas as to how to prevent that (not serialization of course, but the way it is being serialized)?

Comment: @NubieJ This is because the serilization is done outside of a entitiy manager context. You could use something like the sessionPerView pattern, or try to load the object compleate, before it is serialized.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In fact I have a unidirectional relation (exp: Department has many Employee). So Employee will have a foreign key on Department.
Once generated, Hibernate do a bidirectional relation with ManyToOne and OneToMany.
So check weather you relation is uni or Bi-directional. In the first case, you need to remove the mapping oneToMany (from Department)

Hope that it will help.