# Decide which class is owning side in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, jpa, set

I have `Role` class, which is the main entity for User's roles and 2 **FK** in this table, which are pointed on two dictionaries independently: `Privelege` and `Unit` classes.

So it's many (`Role`) to one (`Privelege`/`Unit`) relationships as I take.

**Qustions:**

1. Is the Hibernate's mapping in my code correct?
2. Which class is the "owning side" in my case and why?
3. In which class should I write `@JoinColumn` and where `mappedBy`?

As I have read in other posts: *"`@JoinColumn` annotation is maintained in the class which owns the foreign key."*

But in Hibernate's doc I see that `mappedBy` is used on the owning side (see *Example 163. Bidirectional `@OneToOne`*). 
4. What will happen if I remove some `Role` records? If I remove some records from dictionaries will it affect `Role`'s records? Can I override this behavior to disable cascading?

I assume that my "Role" class is the owning side because it has FK pointed on 2 dictionaries. So it owns FK. Therefore I need to use `@JoinColumn` here as its owning side and `mappedBy` at two dictionaries, because it's mapped by owning side. Am I right.

Update: is the "owning side" synonym to "parent side"?

**Role class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ROLES_NEW", schema="MAPP")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ROLENAME")
    private String roleName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UNIT_ID")
    private Unit unit;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRIVELEGE_ID")
    private Privelege privelege;

...

}
```

**Privelege class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRIVELEGES", schema="MAPP")
public class Privelege /*implements GrantedAuthority*/ {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "PRIVELEGENAME", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String privelegeName;

    @Column(name = "descr", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String descr;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "privelege")
    Set<Role> role;

...

}
```

**Unit class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UNITS", schema="MAPP")
public class Unit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "UNITNAME")
    private String unitname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "unit")
    Set<Role> role;

   ...

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the child entity owns the relationship, because that's the side the foreign key is on. This mapping is the most efficient in case of `@ManyToOne`.

Same thing would apply for many-to-many relationships mapped as two bidirectional `@ManyToOne`. It can also be done with `@JoinTable` annotation, but this approach is less efficient.

In case of `@OneToOne` although child (foreign key holder) owns the relationship, the best performance can be obtained, when using `@MapsId` and `@JoinColumn` on the parent side. More about that exception can be found [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

When it comes to `mappedBy` it's simple - it's used when the relationship is bidirectional and on the side `@JoinColumn` is **not** (child has `@JoinColumn`, parent - `mappedBy`).

I recommend Vlad Mihalcea's blog when it comes to optimal hibernate mapping: [one-to-many](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), [many-to-many](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

P.S.: Prefer `List` to `Set` to map -to-many relationship ([source](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-favoring-sets-vs-bags/)).

Comment: You write "the child entity owns the relationship, because that's the side the foreign key is on". But I have Role class which has FK and "@JoinColumn hint", so it owns relationship and can be called "parent side"? Where I'm wrong?

Comment: @user3434906 "owning side" is not a synonym of "parent class", it's the other way around. `Role` in your example owns the relationship (has fk), hence it's a child entity. Check out this answer for those terms clarification: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5340916/7606764